# Command to find whether ideal is binomial in Mathematica?

Tags: algebra

Consider the ideal $$I=\left\{p_2 \left(p_3^2-p_4^2\right) \left(p_5 p_6+p_7\right),-\left(p_2 p_3-p_1 p_4\right) \left(p_5 p_6+p_7\right),-\left(p_3+p_4\right) \right\}.$$

[Corollary 1.3](http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9401001v1.pdf) gives a technique to use elimination ideal repeatedly to test whether the ideal is binomial. Macaulay2 has the Binomials package but some unexpected results [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738055/binomial-ideals-that-are-not-toric-i-e-binomial-and-not-prime).

*Is there a command to test whether an ideal is binomial in Mathematica?*

Comment: `In[111]:= 
ii = {p2*(p3^2 - p4^2)*(p5*p6 + p7), (p2*p3 - p1*p4)*(p5*p6 + p7), 
   p3 + p4};
gb = GroebnerBasis[ii]

Out[112]= {p3 + p4, p1 p4 p5 p6 + p2 p4 p5 p6 + p1 p4 p7 + p2 p4 p7}` That should tell you it does not have exclusively binomial generators